# Calculating data in a table

Tags: probability-or-statistics

i would like to calculate some probability and for that i need - of course - the difference between two values.

i have done it this way

```
CDF[NormalDistribution[average, standardDeviation], x1] - CDF[NormalDistribution[average, standardDeviation], x0]
```

and add the values manually.

how could i do it more easily and get it in a table or so.
The intervalls are fix -- for instance delta=2

many thanks

Comment: The difference between two distributions are better calculated via [TransformedDistribution](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedDistribution.html): `TransformedDistribution[
 x - y, {x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]], 
  y \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]]}]`. Then you can use it as the normal distribution. Also, it's not quite clear why you can't use `NormalDistribution[0, Sqrt[2] Abs[\[Sigma]]]`, - it's the resulting one.

Comment: @m0nhawk, actually what OP is computing is effectively equivalent to $$\int_{x_0}^{x_1}\mathtt{PDF[NormalDistribution[}\mu,\sigma\mathtt{]},x\mathtt{]}\mathrm dx$$; that won't apply here.

Comment: Anyway: are you aware of `Probability[]`?

Comment: thank you for all your tips. i will do it manually then again. it is easier and i know what i am doing :D